# Detemine all elements at a given point js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on an API that use shapes (and irregular) shapes to build websites. My problem is where I can provide a div that can carry as a background to irregular shapes so .

However to do this I would need to know the max area the object is taking up by having the max height and width.

I am aware that `element.getBoundingClientRect` does this but my roadblock is that is does not consider any psuedo elements, which is how most of these shapes are made.

I know when working with the CSS transform property, especially using scale, the browser knows to resize the whole shape including the pseudo element that makes up the shape.

It also uses the border-box coordinate system.

However the browser does not provide this information as it comes from the user agent

My main question is how do I access the dimensions the user agent computes for any given element, or how do I find the proper dimensions of a `'getBoundingClientRect'`  that considers an elements psuedo classes

My shapes can be found in the attached links.

httpsmichaelodumosu57.github.iosigma-xi-mu 
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

I can't afford to use any other method to create my shapes because I have limited time on the project, but I do know that the browser can provide me with the information I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have answered my own question. What you want to do is to scale the image to a very small since (since `transform scale()` works perfectly) and place it in a grid box (this could be a div of small size as well. You would run  `document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)` 
(notice the pluralization) on every point in the div containing you shrunked irregular shape and from there you can find the height and width of its bounding box by the difference of the highest range of their respective coordinate values. To center you must place your irregular shape in the bounding box of the background drop with the re-scaled dimensions (remember your skrunked your irregular shape to find them) and have the margin of the inner shape set to zero. This works only if your real (not pseudo element) is to the left most of the screen. Question is how do you position your background when your irregular shape is not properrly centering inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` for getting the element that exists in specific point, but I have not tested it for any kind of shapes.